# Conflicting versions of postgres database and server

Tags: database, postgresql, database-connection, postgresql-9.1

I installed postgres on Mac OS X 10.6.x. 
When I ran for postgres database version:

```
psql --versionpsql (PostgreSQL) 9.1.1
contains support for command-line editing
```

When I checked for the version of the server:

```
psql -c "select version();"                                                                     version                                                                      
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.0.5 on x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0, compiled by GCC i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3), 64-bit
(1 row)
```

So when I run

```
bash-3.2$ psql
psql (9.1.1, server 9.0.5)
WARNING: psql version 9.1, server version 9.0.
         Some psql features might not work.
```

I am not sure what those features are. These versions are conflicting. I am new to using postgres so I dont know how to upgrade just the postgres server. I tried to search for something online but did not find much help. I don't want to uninstall and reinstall postgres. Is there anyway I could use them both together without them conflicting? Or just upgrade the server to the same version as database?

Edit:

```
which psql
/opt/local/lib/postgresql91/bin//psql

which postgres
/opt/local/lib/postgresql91/bin//postgres

ps -eaf|grep postgres
    0    60     1   0   0:00.07 ??         0:00.09 /opt/local/bin/daemondo --label=postgresql90-server --start-cmd /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.postgresql90-server/postgresql90-server.wrapper start ; --stop-cmd /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.postgresql90-server/postgresql90-server.wrapper stop ; --restart-cmd /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.postgresql90-server/postgresql90-server.wrapper restart ; --pid=none
  103  3971  3967   0   0:00.69 ??         0:01.17 postgres: writer process     
  103  3972  3967   0   0:00.67 ??         0:00.88 postgres: wal writer process     
  103  3973  3967   0   0:00.18 ??         0:00.23 postgres: autovacuum launcher process     
  103  3974  3967   0   0:00.19 ??         0:00.21 postgres: stats collector process     
    0  3616  2726   0   0:00.04 ttys000    0:00.06 su postgres
  103  3967  3619   0   0:00.23 ttys000    0:00.34 postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
    0  4559  4055   0   0:00.03 ttys001    0:00.05 su postgres
  103  5922  4560   0   0:00.01 ttys001    0:00.01 grep postgres
```

Thank you.

Comment: How you installed PostgreSQL? Have you modified any config files? What does `which psql` and `which postgres` reports? What does `ps -eaf|grep postgres` reports?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose that you've already had PostgreSQL installed before. Please, confirm this, 'cos in this case you will have to upgrade your database. **This is important step, it is not possible  to just upgrade the software.**

Please, try stopping currently running server. First, check the source of currently running PostgreSQL:

```
sudo launchctl list | grep -Ei "macports|postgres"
```

Then perform:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w <OldPostgreSQL.plist>
```

and start a new server like this:

```
sudo launchctl load -w <NewPostgreSQL.plist>
```

I would expect new plist to be
 `/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.postgresql91-server.plist`.

---

**In case you need to upgrade:**

1. Make sure you do a full dump of the database first with the *new* version of `pg_dump`.
2. Execute *new* version of the `initdb` in the new `PGDATA` folder.
3. Start a *new* server as outlined above.
4. Upload the full dump.

Here's a [small description](https://wiki-bsse.ethz.ch/display/ITDOC/Upgrade+PostgreSQL+on+Mac+OS+X) I've came across on the subject. And this is the [official PostgreSQL documentation on upgrading between major releases](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/upgrading.html).

Comment: Note the small section at the bottom of the referenced documentation for non-pg_dump methods for upgrade. You can usually convert with just a few minutes of down time using pg_upgrade, even for terabytes of data.  If you need down time measured in the seconds, look into the slony replication approach. Note that any of these methods requires having both versions of the software available at the same time.

Answer (score 5):

Mine was a homebrew install and here's what I did (brought me to a functioning psql with no version issues) -- I'm trying to install KyngChaos's mac build of postgresql

step 0:

```
brew uninstall postgresql
```

step 1:

```
which psql
/path/to/psql  #in my case: /usr/bin/psql
sudo rm /path/to/psql
```

step 2:

```
#inside ~/.bash_profile
export PATH=/usr/local/pgsql-9.3/bin:$PATH
```

step 3:

```
psql
#works
```

Comment: Why did you remove the psql location? (Which is `/usr/bin/psql`)

Comment: Add a little more description to your steps, please?

Answer (score 1):

This may happen if you already had a version of PostgreSQL before new installation.

Since you have two versions of PostgreSQL, you need two versions of psql. Basically, now when you type psql, your system may not be certain to which version of database you are trying to connect.

Remove the previous version. Or install new psql along with new version of the server.

Comment: mm that was something I want to avoid. But I guess there is no easy way to just update server. Thank you.